# how to use socket.io through google load balancing

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, google-cloud-platform

We are having some problems when trying to connect `socket.io` to a `node.js` `compute engine` instance through `google load balancing`.

If I connect from my browser directly to the external `IP` of my `node.js` everything works fine.

If I try to connect to this same `node.js` through the `load balancing` (which will be the production architecture), the `socket` keeps disconnecting all the time.

We tried to configure Load Balancing with sessionAffinity without success.

Any tips? Thanks

Comment: You definitely need session affinity. You should also look into timeout settings in the load balancer configuration. I think it defaults to 30 seconds.

Comment: Having some problems too, session affinity (ip) is on, backend timeout is at 24 hours, nginx keep alive is at 650 as recommended. I run the same app without the load balancer on mt "test" environment and I don't have the issue.

Comment: @Rhangaun Try this please https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#client_ip_affinity. My team had similar issues with Azure load balancer and sticky sessions helped. Please let me know if it works, if yes, I will post it as answer.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite did you read my comment -> "session affinity (ip) is on".

Answer (score 2):

By Default The timeout set for http load balancing is 30 seconds by default ([Source](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#websocket_proxy_support)), this applies to web sockets which in turn is used by socket.io when the protocol is supported by the back-end. Therefore you need to do the following to increase the time out ([Source](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#timeout-setting)).

To configure the timeout setting:

- GO TO THE LOAD BALANCING PAGE
- Select the Edit pencil for your load balancer.
- Select Backend configuration.
- Select the Edit pencil for the Backend service.
- On the line for Protocol, Port, and Timeout settings, select the Edit pencil.
- Enter a new Timeout Setting in seconds.
- Click the Update button for the load balancer.

Comment: @Rhangaun That was a comment that gave a suggestion into the right direction, this answer further elaborates the steps to do it and cites the sources for future use if someone other than the original poster comes across the same situation according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: First, my comment included "backend timeout is at 24 hours", second, IMHO, this "step-by-step" style of answer is not what is expected on SO.

Comment: @Rhangaun I was answering the question, not your comment. While there is a remote connection to your issue and this question and you're the one offering the bounty, I would still prioritize the actual question over what as far as I can see a separate issue. I think it would have been better if you asked a separate question with your specific issue rather than take over an existing question.